# Binding RenderSize/DesiredSize in ControlTemplate gives odd behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a custom ControlTemplate and running into issues. I am drawing a series of PolyLines to create the border effect and having trouble getting this to show up in both the Designer and at runtime.

In order to draw the PolyLines, I need the control's ActualHeight and ActualWidth to generate the PointCollection. Binding to DesiredSize and RenderSize, however, are producing very odd results. The first time I change the Path to either DesiredSize or RenderSize, it shows up correctly in the designer like this:

[image]

. However, when I actually run the test application, the results I get are all screwed up like this:

[image]

and the Converter is getting 0,0 for the Size.

**My question: What is going on and how can I fix it?**

My PolyLine XAML (There are 6 of these in total that are exactly the same except for ConverterParameter and Opacity changing):

```
<Polyline Stroke="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Opacity="1"
            Points="{Binding Path=RenderSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BConverter}, ConverterParameter=0 }">
</Polyline>
```

The Converter code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    Size renderSize = (Size)value;
    double ActualHeight = renderSize.Height;
    double ActualWidth = renderSize.Width;
    double DiagonalOffset = 10;
    double BaseOffset = 1;
    double AdditionalOffset = double.Parse(parameter.ToString());

    double Offset = BaseOffset + AdditionalOffset;

    PointCollection r = new PointCollection();

    r.Add(new Point(0 + Offset, ActualHeight - Offset));
    r.Add(new Point(0 + Offset, DiagonalOffset));
    r.Add(new Point(DiagonalOffset, 0 + Offset));
    r.Add(new Point(ActualWidth - Offset, 0 + Offset));
    r.Add(new Point(ActualWidth - 0.5 - Offset, ActualHeight - DiagonalOffset));
    r.Add(new Point(ActualWidth - DiagonalOffset, ActualHeight - 0.5 - Offset));
    r.Add(new Point(0 + Offset, ActualHeight - 0.5 - Offset));

    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems with RenderSize, and they were caused by the fact that RenderSize is no dependency property and values thus didn't update automatically. In my opinion having some properties behave different from the rest is really bad API design, but it's WPF so I guess we shouldn't really be surprised.
In my case the solution was to use ActualWidth and ActualHeight which are dependency properties.